# how to get the sum of python dictionary listed as a tuple?

Tags: python

I have python dictionary listed as tuples as follows; Here the first value of  the each tuple depicts the group number and each dictionary depicts the generated value related to the each number inside the group, (i.e., {'1': 0,'3': 1,'2': 1,'5': 2,'303': 3}.

```
[('1',{'1': 0,'3': 1,'2': 1,'5': 2,'303': 3}), ('2',{'4': 0,'5': 1,'7': 1,'5': 2,'303': 2}), ('3',{'1': 0,'3': 0,'2': 0,'5': 2,'303': 3})]
```

Is there any method to get the sum of the each group by getting the sum of the each group, (i.e.,

```
[('1', 7), ('2', 6), ('3', 5)]
```

I tried to iterate over the each value and get the sum but that method is so expensive.

Comment: "I tried to iterate over the each value and get the sum but that method is so expensive." What do you mean by "expensive"? Did you manage to write code that gives a correct answer? What actually is the difficulty here? We don't generally take questions about code style or elegance, unless you have some objective metric in mind. Also, what does any of this have to do with `pandas` or `networkx`? Please do not use tags just because of the overall task you have to perform - only tag according to *what is needed to understand the problem correctly*.

Comment: How are you getting those sums? Are you summing the product of the int value of each key with their associated value? If so the desried result you give doesn't match with any of the given example tuples

Comment: @joshmeranda I think it's just the sum of the values of the corresponding dict.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel ah that makes sense, I was going in the wrong direction

Comment: Please try to break the problem down into parts and think about it logically. Given `{'1': 0,'3': 1,'2': 1,'5': 2,'303': 3}`, can you write code that gives you the right answer? Given a tuple like `('1', x)` where `x` is the dict, do you see how to use the code from the first step in order to get the desired tuple of output? Given a list of such tuples, do you see how to apply the code from the second step to each tuple in the list? Where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 2):

A simple list comprehension should so

```
>>> [(k, sum(dic.values())) for k, dic in tuples]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
lst = [
    ("1", {"1": 0, "3": 1, "2": 1, "5": 2, "303": 3}),
    ("2", {"4": 0, "3": 1, "7": 1, "5": 2, "303": 2}),
    ("3", {"1": 0, "3": 0, "2": 0, "5": 2, "303": 3}),
]

sum_of_each_group = [(i, sum(d.values())) for (i, d) in lst]

print(sum_of_each_group)

# output: [('1', 7), ('2', 6), ('3', 5)]
```